# Calculator Class Functions

Tags: c++, class, getter-setter

This is a very simple `C++` question but i can not get this.
I was doing a work and question came that create a simple calculator class which performs different operations. I have done this easily through methods but it says more that

> "Every operation performed by the calculator object must be stored in
>   the object’s memory, which can be get or set by the user further."

As a hint the book have given two methods

```
voidSetMem(double d);
double GetMem();
```

I can not understand what does this line means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undertanding Getter / Setter Methods

Basically a 'Getter' is a function that returns the data stored in some variable, in you're text book hint

```
double getMem()
{
//Return your data
return memoryVariable;
}
```

And your 'Setter' would be a function used to set some variable

```
void setMem (double variableToPass)
{
memoryVariable = variableToPass
}
```

Notice two things: 
1.) The getter function returns a data type double (because you are asking the program to provide you with data already set/stored
2.) The setter function returns NO data type (because you are telling/setting some variable)

Here is a basic example to GET the area from a square:

```
double getArea()
{
   return pow(side, 2);
}
```

Now in your program you would obtain this data like so:

```
cout << " The area of the circle is " << sq1.getArea() <<"\n";
```

Here is a basic example to SET the area from a square:

```
 void setSide(double newSide)
{
    side = newSide;
}
```

And in your program you would set this data like so:

```
 sq1.setSide(50);
```

Hope This answers your question. Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

As far as the instruction goes, it could be possible if you perform calculation normally and just store its result in the object.

In your `calculator` class, make a variable which stores the last calculation performed. These two functions would be able to store the value in that variable and fetch the value of the last calculation performed. 
Suppose you have this sort of structure.

```
class Calculator
{
  private :
    double last_result ;
  public:
    void setMem(const double) ;
    double getMem ()const ;

} ;
```

Inside these functions, you can just make the incoming value equal to the value in that object.

In your main, you would do like this.

```
double _result = 3.4 * 6 ;
Calculator c_obj ;
c_obj.setMem(_result) ;
```

If you want to output the result or use it somewhere else in your program, make use of the `getMem()` function.

```
cout << "Last Result was :" << c_obj.getMem() << endl ;
```

Comment: But what does get memory means?